# How to connect my mysql VM and my Azure web Site

Tags: php, mysql, azure

I would like to connect my Unix Virtual Machine (who hosted mariaDB and phpmyadmin) at my php web site hosted on Azure Web Site.
My virtual machine doesn't use virtual networks. I opened endpoint and I added one rule on iptables, but my php web site doesn't manage to connect on the VM.

If someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify if you added an endpoint for port 3306 on the VM?

Comment: Yes I've already added this endpoint on my VM

Answer (score 0):

If you have opened 3306 port at your VM, please check your mysql db settings for example remote connection allowed or your connection user previlleges.